# How can we modify almost any algorithm to have a good best-case running time?

Tags: algorithm

This is a question from [*Introduction to Algorithms*](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms-third-edition) by Cormen et al, but this isn't a homework problem. Instead, it's self-study.

I have thought a lot and searched on Google. The answer that I can think of are:

- Use another algorithm.
- Give it best-case inputs
- Use a better computer to run the algorithm

But I don't think these are correct. Changing the algorithm isn't the same as making an algorithm have better performance. Also using a better computer may increase the speed but the algorithm isn't better. This is a question in the beginning of the book so I think this is something simple that I am overlooking.

So how can we modify almost any algorithm to have a good best-case running time?

Comment: Algorithms have best, average and worst case running times. You can't make an algorithm _have_ a best-case running time because it has one anyway. Perhaps you mean _improve_ its best-case running time? Please write the exact question from the book. P.S. The speed of the computer doesn't affect an algorithm's time order.

Comment: Along those lines, I'd imagine best-case running time can be achieved by having zero-length input :D

Comment: @Shahbaz I know that. It got me confused too. But the title of the question is the exact wording from the book CLRS. I have heard a lot of praise for the book so I don't think the statement can be wrong.

Comment: It's not about the algorithm having the best-case running time (after all we can't modify the algorithm to alter the input), but rather how we can guarantee that the best-case is a good one, as also demonstrated in the answer.

Comment: Perhaps, the best-case running time can be achieved by using all available instructions wherever possible and avoiding writing procedures manually in such cases. For example, finding powers of 2 can be done by left shift operation which finds the power in one instruction.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can modify any algorithm to have a best case time complexity of `O(n)` by adding a special case, that if the input matches this special case - return a cached hard coded answer (or some other easily obtained answer).

For example, for any sort, you can make best case `O(n)` by checking if the array is already sorted - and if it is, return it as it is.

Note it does not impact average or worst cases (assuming they are not better then `O(n)`), and you basically improve the algorithm's best case time complexity.

---

Note: If the size of the input is bounded, the same optimization makes the best case `O(1)`, because reading the input in this case is `O(1)`.

Comment: Unless that bound is hardcoded in the algorithm (which I've never heard of)`(1)`, in our current universe, all applications have bounded input. So the fact that you can't give an algorithm more numbers won't make it O(1). `(1)` For example `sum = 0; for i = 0 to 100: sum += array[i];` is an algorithm of O(1), but of course no one hardcodes sizes in the algorithm.

Comment: @Shahbaz Though I agree to the theoretic concept, yes - if an algorithm has a bounded input, then there is final set of inputs and thus final set of possible runs, and the solution is `O(1)` (bounded by the longest run from these), the idea was that if your input is a 32bit int, reading it is `O(1)`, but iterating over it from 1 to `n` is usually considered `O(n)`, even though theoretically it is indeed `O(1)`.

Comment: I was opposing to your last sentence, saying the algorithm would be O(1) if it has bounded input. What I was saying is that there's basically no algorithm that says "I only accept input bounded by this much". So theoretically, they are _not_ O(1). Practically, all algorithms in this world are O(1). In short, that sentence is useless.

Comment: @Shahbaz, `sumOfAllNumbersUpTo(int x)` gets a bounded size input (Let's assume 32 bits). Now, if the algorithm is naively doing for `(int i = 0; i < x; i++) count += i`, it is usually considered `O(n)` (though in practice it is `O(1)`, because the run time is bounded by `MAX_INT`), but if you cache the value for MAX_INT and answer immidiately without the loop - only for it, the best case of this algorithm is `O(1)`

Comment: It is not "usually considered O(n)", it _is_ O(n). That's an algorithm. `n` being a 32-bit value limited to `MAX_INT` is the problem of the implementation of the algorithm, which doesn't change the order of the algorithm in any way. It's correct that if without looking at some huge input, just by knowing its size you may know the answer, but that's quite unlikely and in truth quiet useless.

Answer (score 5):

If we could introduce an instruction for that very algorithm in the computation model of the system itself, we can just solve the problem in one instruction.

But as you might have already discovered that it is a highly unrealistic approach. Thus a generic method to modify any algorithm to have a best case running time is next to impossible. What we can do at max is to apply tweaks in the algorithm for general redundancies found in various problems.

Or you can go naive by taking the best case inputs. But again that isn't actually modifying the algorithm. In fact, introducing the algorithm in the computation system itself, instead of being highly unrealistic, isn't a modification in the algorithm either.

Answer (score 1):

**The ways we can modify the algorithm to have a best case running time are:**

> - If the algorithm is at the point of its purpose/solution , For ex, for an increasing sort , it is already ascending order sorted and so on .
> - If we modify the algorithm such that we output and exit for its purpose only hence forcing multiple  nested loops to be just one

Answer (score 0):

We can sometimes use a randomized algorithm, that makes random choices, to allow a probabilistic analysis and thus improve the running time..

Comment: that's not improving an algorithm, that's just using a different algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way for this problem is the input to the algorithm. Because the cases in time complexity analysis only depend on our input, how complex it is, how much times it tends to run the algorithm. on this analysis, we decide whether our case is best, average or worst.
So, our input will decide the running time for an algorithm in every case.
Or we can change our algorithm to improve for all cases(reducing the time complexity).

These are the ways we can achieve good best-case running time.

Answer (score 0):

We can modify an algorithm for some special-case conditions, so if the input satisfies that condition, we can output the pre-computed answer. Generally, the best case running time is not a good measure for an algorithm. We need to know how the algorithm performes in worst case.

Answer (score 0):

i just reached to this discussion while looking for an answer. what i think there is only one way to make any algorithm best case by having it a fixed input instead of varing input. if we have an fixed input always the cost and time complexity will always be O(1)